# HTML image positioning

Tags: html, uiwebview, position, image

I'm trying to create a html document to be shown on iphone and ipad.

It's a simple one but I've some problems with the image position and I'm not sure if I should use relative or absolute position.

What I'd like to have is an image in the center of the page, (a litte bit under the top of the screen) and a youtube iframe centered under the image.

This code is working on portrait but not on landscape as the image will not be in the center if the page.

I'd like also to have some space between the image and the youtube frame.
This is my actual code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<meta content="width=device-width;" initial-scale="1.0;" maximum-scale="2.0;" name="viewport" user-scalable="1;" />
<body bgcolor="#9fa2b5">
   <div align="center">
      <img style="position:relative; TOP:15px; LEFT:65px; "src="http://mysite.jpg" alt="image is missing"  width=90 height=130>
      <p>
      </p>

      <iframe  width="320" height="180" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed" frameborder="1" ></iframe>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different techniques to centre page contents and a few are discussed at [this article on w3.org](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html).  You are using the `align` attribute on the `div`, and it should work.  However, in the image tag you are also adding `left:65px;` which will move the image `65px` to the right of centre.

In a pure css solution, you should do the following to the html.

```
<div class="container">
    <img class="rndImage" src="http://myimage.org" alt="image is missing"/>
    <iframe class="youtube" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed" frameborder="1" ></iframe>
</div>
```

And add the following CSS in `style` block or in an attached css style sheet.

```
iframe.youtube
{
    width:320px;
    height:180px;
    display:block;
    margin:15px auto;
}

img.rndImage
{
    display:block;
    width:90px;
    height:130px;
    margin:15px auto;
}

div.container
{
   position:relative;
   width:100%;
   margin:5px, auto;
}
```

The above code separates out the style from the html and links it by using classes.  You can see a working example [on JsFiddle.Net](http://jsfiddle.net/GWmxv/1/).

Comment: Thanks, working fine on desktop but still not centered in moblile safari

Comment: The image is not centered; it's rendered on the left side of the page